# I want to add a currency symbol in front of textform field,without the use of a package.[Flutter]

Tags: flutter

i want to place a Celsius symbol and other symbold in front of my textfields in flutter.
`

```
CustomTextField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                          RegExp(r'[0-9]'),
                        ),
                      ],
                      onSaved: (value) {},
                      hint: '',
                      controller: _vlaueofvehicle,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter the degree in celsius  (°)';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
```

`

i used rows  but it pushed the text away by padding.

Comment: You want it as a hint or label? or do you want it inside the textfield were the user inputs the data?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextField.decoration.prefix` property.